# Sorting a DataTable by columns in a file

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, csv, text-files

I am reading a csv file and sorting it.

I am trying to sort a DataTable to give me a output based on Bankname from datatable

**here is the code I already have:**

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("accountholder", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("accountnumber", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("accounttype", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("bankname", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("branch", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("amount", typeof(double));
            dt.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));

            string line;

        //CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\\Test\\debitorders.csv");
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\\Test\\output.txt");

        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Length > 0)
            {
                string[] inputArray = line.Split(new char[] { ',' });
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    inputArray[0].Trim().Substring(0,1),
                    inputArray[1].Trim(),
                    long.Parse(inputArray[2].Trim()),
                    inputArray[3].Trim(),
                    inputArray[4].Trim(),
                    inputArray[5].Trim(),
                    (long)(100 * double.Parse(inputArray[6].Trim())),
                    DateTime.Parse(inputArray[7].Trim())
                });



                DateTime date = account.Field<DateTime>("date");
                string[] outputLine = new string[]{
                    initial,
                    accountholder,
                    accountnumber.ToString(),
                    accounttype,
                    bankname,
                    branch,
                    amount.ToString(),
                    date.ToShortDateString()
                };
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",outputLine));
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: This can be done far easier and nicer by using [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/). You also don't seem to be closing your StreamReader and StreamWriter; you'd best [encapsulate them in a using statement](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhyTheUsingStatementIsBetterThanASharpStickInTheEyeAndASqlConnectionRefactoringExample.aspx).

Comment: Moreover, you don't use the StreamWriter, instead you output to Console. Where is `Field<string>("Surname")` coming from? I'd advise to restructure your code, split it up into smaller bits: read the raw data, convert the raw data into properly formatted data, write the output... IMHO there are far too many issues with this code to expect anyone to help you.

Comment: ("Surname" ) and ("Initial") make up "accountholder". The code is not yet finished, so I'm still stuck. I just want a easier way of doing it

Comment: You're likely stuck because you're trying to do it all at once. Split your work into smaller methods, for instance first try to read the raw data into an easy to use format: a custom class and not a `DataTable`. Then convert that "raw" data into the data as you would like to see it, and then write these properly formatted data to a file. Your code as posted is severely broken, and I doubt you'll find anyone here who'll do your work for you.

Comment: You might want to hide sensitive data, like account numbers etc...

Comment: @akemp this is just an example, not real account numbers

Comment: @BCdotNET I will take your advise and split my work. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code and posted desired result doesn't seem to be consistent so you probably have to adapt my code to your needs. But my code example will show you how to get rid of the DataTable and DataRow stuff. Instead LINQ methods are used where possible and a simple helper method for reading the csv file. If you have any further questions about the code let me know.

```
//reading the csv and create anonymous object for each line
var inputEntries = File.ReadLines(@"C:\\Test\\debitorders.csv")
.Select(line => 
        {
            var values = line.Split(','); 
            return new 
            {
                AccountHolder = values[0].Trim().Substring(0,1) + values[1].Trim(), 
                AccountNumber = long.Parse(values[2].Trim()),
                AccountType = values[3].Trim(),
                BankName = values[4].Trim(),
                Branch = values[5].Trim(),
                Amount = 100 * double.Parse(values[6].Trim()),
                Date = DateTime.Parse(values[7].Trim())
            };
        });

var banks = inputEntries
        .OrderBy(e => e.BankName)
        .GroupBy(e => e.BankName, e => e);

//output data
foreach(var bank in banks)
{
    //output bank header
    var AccountName = bank.Key;
    if (AccountName.Length >= 16)
    {
        AccountName = AccountName.Substring(0, 16);
    }
    else
    {
        AccountName += new string(' ', 16 - AccountName.Length);
    }
    var NumberOfAccounts = bank.Count();
    var TotalAmount = bank.Select(acc => acc.Amount).Sum();
    var Header = NumberOfAccounts.ToString("000") + TotalAmount.ToString("0000000000");
    Console.WriteLine(Header);

    //sort accounts
    var sortedAccounts = bank
                        .OrderBy( acc=> acc.AccountHolder)
                        .OrderByDescending(acc => acc.Amount);

    //output accounts
    foreach( var account in sortedAccounts)
    {
        var outputLine =
            account.AccountHolder +
            account.AccountNumber +
            account.AccountType +
            account.Amount + 
            account.Date.ToShortDateString();

        Console.WriteLine(outputLine);
    }
}
```